# RejectedExecutionException even when ExecutorService is guarded by isShutdown()

Tags: java, executor

I've got a problem that's been driving me nuts for a while and I need to consult your collective wisdom.

I have a ThreadPoolExecutor with a pool of 1, called from Executors.newFixedThreadPool. I guard all executor.execute() with !isShutdown() since executor.shutdown() is called from another thread, and so should be able to say that the executor will not throw a RejectedExecutionException. Nevertheless, this is what I'm seeing randomly.

Does anyone have a good idea why I'm seeing this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

You might go through an article on [double-checked locking](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html) in order to understand how/why an unsynchronized "if then act" approach doesn't work in java.

Out of curiosity, why do you bother to check if the work will be rejected? I can't remember seeing this done before. Instead, why not catch and handle any RejectedExecutionExceptions that are thrown?

Also be careful of how you're handling other error conditions, especially tasks that are running or waiting in the queue when shutdown is called. Chapter 7 of Java Concurrency in Practice has lots of good information about this.

Comment: I actually didn't have the check before, until I started getting RejectedExecutionExceptions. I've changed my code to simply catch the exceptions now, thanks. As an aside, I've realised I do have the Java Concurrency in Practice book, and it's high time I read it again.

Answer (score 0):

There are other reasons for rejected execution that are spelled out here http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html

Most likely your queue reached it's bounds.

Comment: From the javadocs, newFixedThreadPool creates a thread pool that reuses a fixed number of threads operating off a shared unbounded queue, therefore it should never have this issue.

Comment: My bad. I missed that you use fixed thread pool. Other thing that I can think of is some concurrency issue when thread pool is marked shutdown after check but before task is submitted. May be you could synchronize around?

Comment: That does seem like the only explanation left, doesn't it? Thanks for the suggestion :)